# Order of columns in GROUP BY clause does affect index use

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This is more of an academic question, because in my particular case I can create an easy workaround, but I would like to understand the reason behind this anyway.

Using an InnoDB table (MariaDB 10.0.31) with (among others) columns customer and uri, I wanted to select the distinct uris for a specific customer. Now, the table is quite large (around 50M entries), so there is a composite index on customer and uri.

Basically what I don't understand is why the order of the columns in the group by clause matters.

```
explain select customer, uri from `tableName` group by customer,uri;
```

tells me it will use the existing index for group by, but

```
explain select customer, uri from `tableName` group by uri,customer;
```

won't do so.

Could someone explain why this is the case? I always thought of the group by clause as declarative.

Maybe it's because it's Friday, but I can't think of a case, where the order of the group by columns would affect the result.

Comment: Side note: it's usually more idiomatic to use `DISTINCT` if you have no aggregate columns

Comment: Sure, this was just an example. The actual query needs group bys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observation is correct. Results would be different as the **"prefix"** order of columns mentioned in the composite index declaration is used for decision making by the Cost based optimizer. This behavior is due to the usage of B-TREE index

GROUP BY clause is used for ordering the result and hence if

- the correct order of index is used or
- only leftmost columns are used in group by
- leftmost column is used in WHERE clause and rest in correct order in GROUP BY clause index would be used.

More on this and topic of **Loose/Tight Index Scan** can be found here
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

In index is basically an ordered table. In you case it is ordered according like `ORDER BY customer, uri` (because this is how your index is defined).

MySQL executes `group by` by first ordering the result according to the `group by` clause and then collapsing the rows with the same values (that happen to follow each other after sorting).

Apparently, MySQL is not smart enough to recognize that the different `group by` clause could also be executed when the result is ordered the other way.

More about this:

- http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping
- In particular: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-group-by

Comment: Yeah, I understand how a composite index works, that's not the problem. I just can't get my head around why mysql will not use the existing index. There must be some reason for this, because it seems so easy to implement an engine that would permute the group by elements and try to find an index. I will try this out in Postgres and see if it behaves the same way.

Comment: @FelixS . . . Given MySQL's optimizer, you should be impressed that it manages to use an index for *any* `group by` at all.  Maybe version 8 will be better.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I think I remember something in the documentation a fair while back about it only using one index per _statement_ too?  ouch.

Answer (score 0):

Write a feature request at bugs.mysql.com .

On the one hand, `GROUP BY` is (or was) defined to imply `ORDER BY` with the same columns in the same order.

On the other hand, if you ignore that non-standard feature, even by saying `ORDER BY NULL`, MySQL fails to shuffle the columns in order to use the index.

[*5.7 (and before)*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) says

> GROUP BY implicitly sorts by default (that is, in the absence of ASC
>   or DESC designators), but relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting is
>   deprecated. To produce a given sort order, use explicit ASC or DESC
>   designators for GROUP BY columns or provide an ORDER BY clause. GROUP
>   BY sorting is a MySQL extension that may change in a future release;
>   for example, to make it possible for the optimizer to order groupings
>   in whatever manner it deems most efficient and to avoid the sorting
>   overhead.

and

> If a query includes GROUP BY but you want to avoid the overhead of
>   sorting the result, you can suppress sorting by specifying ORDER BY
>   NULL.

But, watch out; [*8.0*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) says

> Previously, relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting was deprecated but
>   GROUP BY did sort by default (that is, in the absence of ASC or DESC
>   designators). In MySQL 8.0, GROUP BY no longer sorts by default, so
>   query results may differ from previous MySQL versions. To produce a
>   given sort order, use explicit ASC or DESC designators for GROUP BY
>   columns or provide an ORDER BY clause.